# Convergence of the expectation of compositions of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

We know that if $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution, then $E(g(X_n)) \rightarrow E(g(X))$ for bounded, continuous $g$. Let $F_n, F$ be the distribution functions for $X_n, X$. Suppose that $g > 0$ is continuous, $h$ is continuous, and $|h(x)|/g(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$. Also $\int g(x) dF_n (x) \leq C$, where this integral is against the measure induced by $X_n$ on the real line. Under these conditions, I wish to show $E(h(X_n)) \rightarrow E(h(X))$.

I'm not sure how to prove it. I do realize that $E(\frac{h}{g} (X_n)) \rightarrow E(\frac{h}{g} (X))$ and also by Fatou's Lemma for distributional convergence, $E(g(X)) \leq C$. I'm not sure how to use these observations, though.